# Showing a "Please wait..." box while slot function is running

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a slot function in my GUI that takes time to complete (10-15 seconds).
I would like to gray the layout and show a box of "Please wait..." that will disappear when the slot function is done.

I need it to be async as I want to use a `QProgressBar` widget in the "Please wait..." Window.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your long running slot should be running in a QThread, while your "Please wait..." widget should be modal in the main GUI thread.

You could use [QProgressDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qprogressdialog.html) and maybe [choose a windowflag](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#WindowType-enum) that suits your display needs, or a custom widget. But the long running operation should signal the modal blocking dialog when it has completed, causing the dialog to then hide.

Comment: If your slot is a repeated a lot loop you can do it without creating new thread. Simply each step call QCoreApplication::processEvents()

Comment: I would take that suggestion with a grain of salt. Yes you can do operations like that in the main thread. You wouldnt call processEvents on every loop, but at intervals. I still think its not the best design since something will end up blocking for some period of time. Ita really just better to put your non gui work into a thread. Its easy to do and easy to emit signals.

Comment: Ofcourse it is not proper for every operation BUT if your "blocking process" consists of only lighweight operations (but plenty of them), then I think it is not best design to put QThread in that place.

Comment: `processEvents` called recursively is problematic because there's nothing to prevent reentering your slot or event handler. It would be a more appropriate design to have the long-running slot chopped up into smaller run-to-completion chunks, and run them back-to-back by posting an event to your `QObject` every time a chunk is complete. This can be done automatically by running a zero-period timer. Timers with zero period are special, they are not really timers but merely flags to trigger a slot or an event every time the event loop finishes spinning (or begins, I forget that detail now).